# Why don't my nested directives work when the markup is in a single file?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been looking at isolateScope directives, to get a better understanding of how they interact with other nested isolateScope directives, so put together a plnkr to test a few things out.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7Tl7GbWIovDSmVeKKN26?p=preview

This worked as expected. As you can see each directive has it's own separate template.

I then decided to move the html out of each directive and into the main html file, but it's stopped working? I can see that the `e1Ctrl` is on the scope of the directive, but it doesn't appear to be available when the enclosed markup is processed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/33Zz1oO4q7BVFw0cMvYa?p=preview

Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

----------- UPDATE -----------

I've simplified the non-working plunker to clearly show the problem. The directive uses the `controllerAs` syntax and the `e1Ctrl` is clearly set on its `$scope` (see the console output).

http://plnkr.co/edit/g2U2XskJDwWKuK3gqips?p=preview

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl)
  .directive('elementOne', elementOne)
  .controller('E1Ctrl', E1Ctrl)


function AppCtrl() {

  var vm = this;

  vm.data = [
  {
    label: 'one'
  },
  {
    label: 'two'
  },
  {
    label: 'three'
  },
  {
    label: 'four'
  }
  ];

  vm.callback = function() {
    console.log('called app callback');
  };
}


function elementOne() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      handler: '&'
    },
    controller: 'E1Ctrl',
    controllerAs: 'e1Ctrl',
    bindToController: true
  }
}

function E1Ctrl($scope) {
  console.log('E1Ctrl', $scope);
  var vm = this;

  vm.click = function() {
    vm.handler();
  };

  vm.callback = function() {
    console.log('called e1 callback');
  };
}
```

Mark up:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as appCtrl">
  <ul>
    <div ng-repeat='item in appCtrl.data'>

      <element-one data='item' handler='appCtrl.callback()'>
        <button ng-click='e1Ctrl.click()'>e1: {{e1Ctrl.data.label}}</button>
      </element-one>

    </div>
  </ul>
</body>
```

------ Transclusion solution -----

http://plnkr.co/edit/l3YvnKOYoNANteNXqRrA?p=preview

```
function elementOne() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      handler: '&'
    },
    controller: 'E1Ctrl',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, transclude) {

      transclude($scope, function(clone){
        $element.append(clone);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. please make your question self-contained, 2. in many places in the second program you use `e1Ctrl` instead of `appCtrl`, and there are other bugs.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what you mean by self contained? You want me to move all the logic from both the plnkrs into the question? Do you think that'll make it more readable? 2. It's supposed to be `e1Ctrl` not `appCtrl`. It's not a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference in scope for HTML in the `template` of the directive and HTML that in a subtree of the directive. The former is evaluated in the context of the scope of the directive; the latter - in the scope of the View.

If the directive has an isolate scope - `scope: {}`, then the subtree doesn't see it. If it uses `scope: true`, then it creates a new child scope for the subtree which prototypically inherits from the View's scope.

Consider the following:

```
// isolate scope
app.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope){
      scope.name = "foo";
    }
  }
});

// child scope
app.directive("bar", function(){
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope){
      scope.name = "bar";
    }
  }
});

app.controller("Main", function($scope){
  $scope.name = "main";
});
```

Here's how the View would render:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <pre>in main: {{name}} will render "main"</pre>
  <foo>
    <pre>in subtree of foo: {{name}} will render "main"</pre>
  </foo>
  <bar>
    <pre>in subtree of bar: {{name}} will render "bar"</pre>
  </bar>
</body>
```

In your case, the subtree is evaluated in the scope of the View - not the directive, and that is why it doesn't work as you expected.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2bSOeAvCHghNUOYdlZ7Z?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

In some cases it may makes sense to evaluate the subtree in the context of the isolate scope of the directive. I've seen this used with directives that allow templating. But be careful with this because the author of the Main View should not know (too much) about the inner workings of the directive (i.e. what is exposed in the inner scope). This would also be difficult to read because you would see variables that do not make sense in the outer scope.

To evaluate the subtree in the isolate scope of the directive, the directive needs to `$compile` the subtree and link it against its scope.

Here's a directive that allows the user to provide a template for each item in the list. The `item` variable is not defined in the main scope, and only makes sense in the context of the directive's isolate scope:

```
<list src="items">
  <item-template>
    {{item.a}} | {{item.b}}
  </item-template>
</list>
```

The directive 'list' is below:

```
app.directive("list", function($compile){
  return {
    scope: {
      src: "="
    },
    link: {
      pre: function(scope, element){
        var itemTemplate = element.find("item-template");
        element.empty();

        var template = angular.element('<div ng-repeat="item in src"></div>')
                              .append(itemTemplate.html());

        element.append(template);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[plunker 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/gqQooGjv0yjUiHOy3236?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was starting to wonder if that might be the case. Is there a way to force the markup inside the directive element to be evaluated in the directive scope?

Comment: Thanks again. I was just in the process of editing my answer with a possible solution using transclusion. Although it's new to me, so i'm not sure how it would work with nested directives.